# What is the meaning of "same as differentiable manifolds"?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

First, for the sphere in above picture, isn't the metric supposed to have $sin^2\theta$ in front of $d\phi^2$? I just need to check

And for the main question, what does it mean by the three manifolds are same as differentiable manifolds? The given maps between them seem like diffeomorphisms, but what do the maps have to do with the metric? Could anyone please explain?

Comment: I don't think differentiable manifolds being the same has anything to do with metrics.  It just means they are diffeomorphic.

Comment: The point is probably that they are the same as differentiable manifolds but not as Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: Don't Riemannian manifolds include differentiable manifolds by definition? The definitions of manifolds I know are from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Answer (score 0):

The examples I, II, III are all diffeomorphic to each other; that's what "the same" means in the context of diffeomorphic manifolds.

And the point of these examples is that the maps do NOT have anything to do with the metric: a diffeomorphism ignores the metric. In order to demonstrate that I, II, and III are all diffeomorphic to each other, you need simply write down formulas for the diffeomorphisms, and that's what is done in the lines I$\iff$II etc. The fact that I, II, III are not *isometric* to each other (meaning that the maps to not preserve the metrics) is irrelevant to the question of whether they are *diffeomorphic* to each other.

And you are right, the sphere picture needs that extra factor.

Comment: First, then are there diffeomorphisms that are also isometries? Second, what the picture above says about compositions of the maps is that the diffeomorphism earned from the composition of $f$ and $g$ is not the same as the diffeomorphism $h$? (surely $f$, $g$, $h$ are the maps given in the picture)

Comment: Yes, a diffeomorphism between two Riemannian manifolds may be an isometry. Or it may not be. You can think of an "isometry" as being a special kind of diffeomorphism.